# Checking similar key pair and then sum it dynamically using reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays

So basically i need to generate a chart, i have the following data

```
    [
        {
            "indessx": "1",
            "type": "A",
            "number": "260",
            "month": "May",
            "date": "01/05/20"
        },
        {
            "indessx": "2",
            "type": "A",
            "number": "320",
            "month": "May",
            "date": "02/05/20"
        },
{
            "indessx": "2",
            "type": "A",
            "number": "320",
            "month": "June",
            "date": "02/06/20"
        },
    ]
```

Now, i need to show a graph using the above data, but the response which i am getting have multiple similar values of month like May in the above snippet.Now i used reduce to get the sum of number from a particular month,
so like for may it a new object will be generated with the number added up 260 + 320

so the new object of array will be like this..

```
  [
        {
            "indessx": "1",
            "type": "A",
            "number": "580", // value after addition
            "month": "May",
        },        
{
            "indessx": "2",
            "type": "A",
            "number": "320",
            "month": "June",
            "date": "02/06/20"
        },
    ]
```

i tried doing this with reduce but stuck on adding a check to see if the month is equal then only add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function. As an input, use your initial data, you've given at the start. As an output, it returns the array you asked for.

```
const getNewData = function(data) {
    let indessx = 1, newData = [];
    data.forEach(el => {
        if(newData.findIndex(element => element.month == el.month) != -1) {
            let curElement = newData[newData.findIndex(element => element.month == el.month)];
            curElement.number = (parseInt(curElement.number) + parseInt(el.number)).toString();
            delete curElement.date;
        } else {
            let newEl = el;
            newEl.indessx = indessx;
            newData.push(newEl);
            indessx++;
        };
    });
    return newData;
};
```